S23 Ultra - USB Debugging - Cannot Enable
i am not able to enable usb debugging and wireless debugging option in S23 Ultra. previously it was working but now it is not working.

It was the new "Auto Blocker" security setting in the latest Android 14. Turning that off fixed it.

It is unfortunate that "Auto Blocker" cannot be enabled if USB debugging is required despite unselecting the "Block software updates by USB cable" option.
